# looping through characters and numbers to create variables

Tags: r

Consider the following `data.frame`:

```
structure(list(chr = c("1A", "1B", "1D", "2A", "2B", "2D"), initial = 
c(210200000L,237700000L, 166200000L, 326300000L, 344400000L, 264400000L), 
end = c(215800000L, 243500000L, 173800000L, 327000000L, 351300000L, 
272500000L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks this way:

```
chr   initial       end
1A 210200000 215800000
1B 237700000 243500000
1D 166200000 173800000
2A 326300000 327000000
2B 344400000 351300000
2D 264400000 272500000
```

I would like to loop through the variables of this dataset in order to have numeric range variables like this:

```
A1 <- 210200000:215800000
B1 <- 237700000:243500000
D1 <- 166200000:173800000
```

So A1,B1,D1... and so forth up to A7,B7,D7.

I know I could create a for loop like this `for (i in 1:7) {...}` but I don't know how could I also loop through the characters `ABD`

Comment: `do.call(Map, c(list(f=function(ign,m,n) m:n), unname(a)))` if `a` is your data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear where you get iterating over A,B,D and 1:7 - your sample data only iterates through 2, but maybe it's just a snippet of your overall data?

Regardless, the function `list2env` can be helpful here. You also need some string manipulation to create valid names by reversing the order of `chr`. Hopefully this gets you on the right track:

```
dat <- structure(list(chr = c("1A", "1B", "1D", "2A", "2B", "2D"), initial = 
                 c(210200000L,237700000L, 166200000L, 326300000L, 344400000L, 264400000L), 
               end = c(215800000L, 243500000L, 173800000L, 327000000L, 351300000L, 
                       272500000L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

sequences <- lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x) dat[x,2]:dat[x,3])

#helper function from ?strsplit
strReverse <- function(x) sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), rev), paste, 
                                 collapse="") 
#you could also use make.names() instead.
names(sequences) <- strReverse(dat$chr)
#specify the global environment - creates an object from each item in the list
list2env(sequences, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Running `ls()` after this yields:

```
> ls()
[1] "A1"         "A2"         "B1"         "B2"         "D1"         "D2"         "dat"        "sequences"  "strReverse"
```